# Inserting comments in presentation using Python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I want to add some comments in presentation file for some text-boxes. Is there any python-pptx attribute available to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerPoint comments are not yet supported in `python-pptx`. There's not really a feature request for that at the time of this writing, so you can feel free to add one if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Recommended reading : https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/text.html

https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html

Hope this helps,

Comment: I have already gone through this document but there is not any option to add a comment  to the slide.

Comment: If you don't find it in the docs, open a issue at the official github repo here : https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx Maybe it isn't implemented yet. If you do open a issue please comment the link here. I am interested to follow up.