# View PPT Comments

Tags: powerpoint, python-pptx

I have a PPT with 500+ slides. It has comments on few slides which I would like to get/extract. It is tough to scroll all 500 slides. Is there a way, I can get all comments at one go?

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Already answered by stolbert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701080/12264569

Answer (score 0):

Your tags mention python but this feels like a one-off problem and since you already have PowerPoint, you can use VBA to solve it.  Like so:

```
Sub ListComments()

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oCom As Comment
Dim sTemp As String
Dim x As Long

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oCom In oSl.Comments
        sTemp = sTemp & oCom.Text & vbCrLf
        For x = 1 To oCom.Replies.Count
            sTemp = sTemp & vbTab & oCom.Replies(x).Text & vbCrLf
        Next
    Next
Next

' This will "print" the result to the immediate window
' Press Ctrl+G in the VBA editor if it's not open
' If there are more comments than the window will allow,
'   you'll need to write the contents of sTemp to file or
'   do something else with it.
Debug.Print sTemp

End Sub
```