# How to edit comments in PowerPoint with Python (python-pptx or pywin32)?

Tags: python, powerpoint, pywin32, python-pptx

I'm trying to edit links in the document.
Every possible place:

- textual link (not hyperlinked text)
- hyperlinked text
- hyperlinks attached to images
- links in comments

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688750/how-to-extract-comments-from-powerpoint-presentation-slides-using-python) thread, but it's only for getting comment's info. I haven't found how to edit comments using pywin32. Since comment's Text is a property, and I haven't see any methods or even private variables to work with comment's text.

In general I'm working with python-pptx, but it seems it doesn't have any comments support.
Does anyone know the solution? I faced the same problem with docx files (python-docx also doesn't have comments support), but I've found a "[bayoo-docx](https://pypi.org/project/bayoo-docx/)" fork which adds comments support to python-docx library.

I even tried to work with xml directly through ZipFile, but I only was able to find info about comments.
Does anyone have an ideas how to edit them?
Again, the main goal is replace links. I mean their textual representation and "target" - the real urls it's refers to.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify whether you want to modify/add *comments* or *hyperlinks*.  They're two different things.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I edited the question. I'm talking about replacing links, in comments too. As I can see now SharePoint displays usual text as hyperlink, so replacing the comment's text only should be enough, I suppose.

Comment: Comments cannot contain links, and I have no idea what you mean by "textual link (not hyperlinked text)".  I think you need to use PowerPoint's own terms to describe what you're after and NOT use PowerPoint's terms when you mean something else.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, by "textual link (not hyperlinked text)" I mean the URL adress which was pasted into a comment. Since comment's doesn't have hyperlinks, it's just a text. So the more specific question is probably "How to edit comment's text in PowerPoint".

Comment: OK, that focuses it better. Another problem arises:  MS has changed the way comments work. Any presentation might have old-style comments or new-style comments. I'm not sure about old-style ones, but for new-style comments you can retrieve the comment's .Text property but it's read-only; you can't change it.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, yes, I already figured it out what it's read=only, I was curious is there some other ways to do it. Since they stored somewhere. 
I believe I'll start hating MS soon :D
Ok, so they are not editable. 
What about old-style comments?

Comment: I found that you can edit the text of comments in the XML. There's a Comments folder in the XML that contains the individual comments. The text of the comment is included there and is editable.